# use of gowdis function in R

Tags: r, distance

I want to use the gowdis function to find the distance between two data samples, but this function produces the NAN value. My data is similar to the following.

```
df1> 
  A      B      C      D      E      F      G      H      I      J 
 tcp   http    198     4      4      0     246     1      0      0
df2>
    A    B      C   D  E F  G  H I J
    1 tcp http 145  1  1 0 255 1 0 0
    2 tcp http 207 11 11 0 255 1 0 0
    3 tcp http 296 10 10 0 255 1 0 0
    4 tcp http 212  9  9 0 255 1 0 0
```

And the code I wrote is as follows

```
W<-nrow(df1)+1
E<-nrow(df1)+nrow(df2)
mixusefull2<- rbind(df1,df2)
dist_mixusefull2<- as.matrix(FD::gowdis(mixusefull2))
idxs_mixusefull2 <- KernelKnn::distMat.knn.index.dist(dist_mixusefull2, 
TEST_indices = c(W:E), k = 1, threads = 1, minimize = TRUE)
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

sample data

```
df1 = as.data.frame(matrix(c('tcp','http', 198, 4, 4, 0, 246, 1, 0, 0), 

                    nrow = 1, ncol = 10), stringsAsFactors = TRUE)

colnames(df1) = toupper(letters[1:10])

df1



df2 = as.data.frame(matrix(c(rep('tcp', 4), rep('http', 4), c(145, 207, 296, 212), 

                           c(1,11,10,9), c(1,11,10,9), rep(0, 4), rep(255, 4), 

                           rep(1, 4), rep(0, 4), rep(0, 4)), nrow = 4, ncol = 10, 

                           byrow = FALSE), stringsAsFactors = TRUE)

colnames(df2) = toupper(letters[1:10])

df2

W<-nrow(df1)+1

E<-nrow(df1)+nrow(df2)

mixusefull2<- rbind(df1,df2)

str(mixusefull2)
```

I converted the columns 3 to 10 to numeric. I don't know the use case of your data but you should know that the *FD::gowdis* function accepts  *numeric*, *ordered*, or *factor* variables (you can take a look using *?FD::gowdis* ). So you probably have to adjust the type of the columns accordingly.

```
for (col in 3:10) {

  mixusefull2[, col] = as.numeric(mixusefull2[, col])
}

str(mixusefull2)


dist_mixusefull2<- as.matrix(FD::gowdis(mixusefull2))

dist_mixusefull2

idxs_mixusefull2 <- KernelKnn::distMat.knn.index.dist(dist_mixusefull2, 

                        TEST_indices = c(W:E), k = 1, threads = 1, minimize = TRUE)

idxs_mixusefull2

$test_knn_idx
     [,1]
[1,]    1
[2,]    1
[3,]    1
[4,]    1

$test_knn_dist
      [,1]
[1,] 0.175
[2,] 0.300
[3,] 0.300
[4,] 0.375
```

I don't receive any NA's. Is the output what you actually expect?

Comment: No, I mean exactly getting the same answer you got but ,In all data, gowdis correctly answers two-thirds And another one-third answers NAN.

Comment: The error I get is as follows.Error in KernelKnn::distMat.knn.index.dist(dist_mixusefull2, TEST_indices = c(W:E),  : 
  the DIST_mat includes missing values

Comment: @maria, can you update your question with the output matrix as well. I don't understand why you get NA's. As I mentioned the first two columns of your input data should be of type factor and the rest of the columns of type numeric.

Comment: For example, in 200 data samples, gowdis responds to 150 data samples (that's mean, the distance calculates), and for the remaining 50 samples,  returns  NAN value.If anyone knows the answer to this question please answer. I need it.thanks a lot